# How to add a self-signed root CA and always trust it from CLI on OSX

Tags: macos, keychain

I succeeded importing a root CA to the keychain with

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain" CA.crt
```

But it's marked as **Use System Defaults**, like

[image]

How can I mark it as **Always Trust** from CLI?

Comment: I just spent an hour. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the only way to modify the trust settings via the security command is by the `trust-settings-import` option.  The xml file output by `security trust-settings-export` would be a good place to start; but, it looks a little tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your root CA certificate is malformed, as your method works for me. Maybe your CA root certificate has not been generated with the expected properties. Try with `-r trustAsRoot` in your case, but I recommend to check your certificate generation.